# Why does my array get filled with objects instead of appending them?

Tags: php

I'm building an app which receives from my server a list of products(for example) and displays them. I am using PHP and Apache to retrieve the list from a SQL Server database(pretty much a REST API). When I am building the array and encoding it, I notice that my array has 10 elements (or more, currently I set this limit for testing) and each one of them is the last one.

I've tried to use `$arr[] = $prod` or `array_push($arr, $prod)`, or creating a temporary array and merging them, but still the same result. I also tried switching from a macOS Apache to a Windows install or Linux one (I thought it might be the Apache/PHP version).

```
$prod = new StdClass(); $arr = array();

$search = $_GET['search'];
$search = "%$search%";

$sql = "SELECT TOP 10
            product, qty
        FROM
            table
        WHERE
            product LIKE ?";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql, array($search));
sqlsrv_execute( $stmt );
$i = 0;
if ( $stmt === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
else {
    while ( $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $prod->mainInfo =  $row['product'];
        $prod->secondInfo = $row['qty'];
        $arr[] = $prod;
    }
}
http_response_code(200);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

The result is something among these lines(there are more lines, but i only include three since it is irrelevant):

```
[
  {
    "mainInfo": "product3",
    "secondInfo": "qty3"
  },
  {
    "mainInfo": "product3",
    "secondInfo": "qty3"
  },
  {
    "mainInfo": "product3",
    "secondInfo": "qty3"
  }
]
```

If there are three products that i am loading. The third product is shown in all of the array's elements. It should be something like this:

```
[
  {
    "mainInfo": "product1",
    "secondInfo": "qty1"
  },
  {
    "mainInfo": "product2",
    "secondInfo": "qty2"
  },
  {
    "mainInfo": "product3",
    "secondInfo": "qty3"
  }
]
```

Comment: Objects update by reference.  Try making a new Product for each iteration or at least use `cone $product`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects in php are always treated **by reference**. So, everytime you modify `$prod` in one place, it is modified everywhere else. To avoid this, `clone` object and work with cloned copy:

```
while ( $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $newProd = clone $prod;
    $newProd->mainInfo =  $row['product'];
    $newProd->secondInfo = $row['qty'];
    $arr[] = $newProd;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Could you explain a little why i should clone a new object, and not move`$prod = new StdClass();` inside the loop like @trincot mentioned? Is this more efficient?

Comment: These are just different approaches. Cloning can be useful when you have some object with already filled properties and don't want to create new object everytime and fill these properties again and again. In case of simple object there's no considerable difference between cloning object and creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying the *same* object over and over again. Even when it was already added to the array, it affects that *single* object. And your arrays just gets multiple references to the same, single object.

To solve this, make sure that `$prod` is a new object at each start of the iteration.

So move this line:

```
$prod = new StdClass();
```

...inside the loop:

```
while ( $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $prod = new StdClass(); // <----
    $prod->mainInfo =  $row['product'];
    $prod->secondInfo = $row['qty'];
    $arr[] = $prod;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `(object)` cast and assign the new object in one go without the need of a `$prod` variable:

```
while ( $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $arr[] = (object) [
        "mainInfo" => $row['product'],
        "secondInfo" => $row['qty']
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects update by reference.

What this means is that the values will dynamically change as you modify the object, even you put the object in the array in the past.  Basically your modifying the same object over and over.

You can create a new instance of the object with `new` or `clone`

```
while ( $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $_prod = clone $prod; //copy the object
    $_prod ->mainInfo =  $row['product'];
    $_prod ->secondInfo = $row['qty'];
    $arr[] = $_prod;
}
```